# Why do I get a Hibernate NonUniqueObject Exception?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, database-design, hibernate-mapping

## I'm trying to  figure out why I am getting this very hard to debug hibernate error and I have narrowed down the triggering behaviour to when I try to save a customer objects which will have a subset of a taris in another customer. Below are the stripped down classes and hbm mappings:

```
**<POJOs>**

public class Tarif {
  private Long idTarifRailingLTD;
  private String name;
  private Set<Customer> customers=new HashSet<Customer>();
}

public class Customer extends Society {
    private Company company;
    private boolean actif;
    private String tvaNumber;
    private Set<Tarif> tarifRailings = new HashSet<Tarif>();
}


**<HBMs>**    
  
<class name="comp.model.accounting.Tarif" table="Tarif" lazy="false">
    <id name="idTarif" type="long">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
        
    <property name="name" length="50" not-null="true"/>
        
    <set name="customers"  table="customer_tarifrailing" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="all">
        <key column="idTarif"/>
        <many-to-many class="comp.model.customer.Customer" column="idCustomer"/>
    </set>
        
</class>

<joined-subclass name="comp.model.customer.Customer" table="customer" lazy="false">
    <key column="idSociety"/>
    <property name="actif" type="boolean"/>
    <property name="tvaNumber" length="80"/>
                
    <many-to-one name="company" class="comp.model.company.Company" column="idCompany" 
                             not-null="true"/>  
                
    <set name="tarifRailings"  table="customer_tarif" inverse="false" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="all">
        <key column="idCustomer"/>
        <many-to-many class="comp.model.accounting.Tarif" column="idTarif"/>
    </set>
                
</joined-subclass>
```

The triggering behaviour, is when I try to persist a customer with a set of tarifs that has a subset (subset must be greater than 1 in number) in another Customer's tarif. For example **customer 1** has **tarif #1 #2 #3 #4**, **customer #2** can have tarifs **#1 #5 #6 #7**, but not tarif **#1 #2 #5 #6** as **#1 #2** is a subset of **#1 #2 #3 #4**. I am not really sure as to why this is at the moment.

```
    **<The Function>**
    public static void addTarifToCustomer(Customer customer, Tarif tarif) throws UserServiceException, Exception {
    
                // Begin unit of work
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                    
                customer.addTarifRailing(tarifRailing);
                    session.saveOrUpdate(customer);
                entKeys = session.getStatistics().getEntityKeys();
                // End unit of work
                session.getTransaction().commit();
                
            } catch (ObjectNotFoundException ex) {
                HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
                throw new NotFoundDAOException("L'object d'identifiant " + customer.getIdSociety()
                        + " n'existe pas dans la base", ex);
            } catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {
                HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
                throw new AlreadyExistDAOException("Nouvel identifiant déja existant en base", ex);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
                throw new Exception(ex);
            }
        }
```

[Stack trace here](http://pastebin.com/zciCaUJF)

Comment: Please paste the exception trace as well.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two instances of Customer class before calling addTarifToCustomer and one of them in detached state? This could cause NonUniqueException. Try to use your ide debugger to see what objects you have before calling line with session.saveOrUpdate();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Luckasz I already knew from the stack trace that it was something like this however as this is an inherited project it was extremely difficult to figure out if another instance was loaded and where, in the end I had to get around this by persisting/update the object in the action layer(controller), rather than going through the DAO layer.
Many thanks to sebersole from the irc channel for helping me to find a way around this.

Comment: Yes your inherited DAO stuff was quite a mess.  It was actually a prime example IMHO about how DAO classes often make working with O/RM *more* difficult.